# Need to send email from within flutter app and in background

Tags: flutter, dart, email

I need to send an email from within the flutter app and I want this to happen in the background.

I have started following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDwst9icjAY and the example in the google signin package https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in but I am getting an error when I add scope. The error message says

```
The instance member 'scopes' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer
```

Here is the code that I am using. It is from the documentation.

```
  List<String> scopes = <String>[
  'email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ];

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  // Optional clientId
  // clientId: 'your-client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scopes: scopes, <<<  ERROR HERE
);
```

Here is where I am trying to send the email:

```
  Future sendNewUserEmail() async {
    final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn.
    final accessToken = '';

    final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2('myapp@gmail.com', accessToken);
    final message = Message()
      ..from = const Address("myapp@gmail.com", "Deal Diligence")
      ..recipients = ['newuser@gmail.com']
      ..subject = "Welcome to Deal Diligence"
      ..text = "Welcome to Deal Diligence. Your password is NewPassword";

    try {
      await send(message, smtpServer);
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

At the line final googleUser = googleSignIn. the example in the documentation shows this:

```
Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
  try {
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

but when I try to do googleSignIn.signIn, the signIn is not a member of googleSignIn.

Does anyone have a current example of how to send email from flutter app that works in the background?

Thanks